# Extract specific users comments from a list using Wikipedia API and Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, wikipedia-api

I am using the wikipedia API - wikitools package to extract some  data from Wikipedia. I get the output of the format shown below and now I want to extract the timestamp and the comment for revisions made of specific user for several pages. Let's say I just want the comments made by TechBot, then I figured that I can do something like:

```
for revision in res["query"]["pages"]["7940378"]["revisions"]:
    if revision["user"] = "Techbot":
        do.something()
```

But the problem is ["7940378"] because this is a unique page id and will change for every page and I dont know how to get the pageid. Is there another way of doing this?

```
[{
"query": {
  "pages": {
    "7940378": {
      "ns": 0, 
      "pageid": 7940378, 
      "revisions": [
        {
          "comment": "robot  Modifying: [[az:T\u00fcrk Tarixi]]", 
          "timestamp": "2009-01-03T19:47:11Z", 
          "user": "TechBot"
        }, 
        {
          "comment": "", 
          "timestamp": "2009-02-14T02:07:49Z", 
          "anon": "", 
          "user": "88.231.237.130"
        }, 
        {
          "comment": "fixing recent deletion by merging it with the next paragraph", 
          "timestamp": "2009-04-03T14:49:27Z", 
          "user": "Soap"
        }, 
        {
          "comment": "robot  Modifying: [[az:T\u00fcrk tarixi]]", 
          "timestamp": "2009-04-09T14:35:19Z", 
          "user": "RibotBOT"
        }, 
        {
          "comment": "Repairing link to disambiguation page - [[Wikipedia:Disambiguation pages with links|You can help!]]", 
          "timestamp": "2009-06-12T23:55:55Z", 
          "user": "J04n"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "History of the Turkic peoples"
    }
  }
}, 
"continue": {
  "rvcontinue": "20090807172715|306635892", 
  "continue": "||"
}, 
"warnings": {
  "main": {
    "*": "Unrecognized parameter: 'user'"
  }
}
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a single for loop.  you can split up into two loops, where the outer loop gets the pages, and with the inner loop you can get to the revisions.

```
for pageid, pagedetails in res["query"]["pages"].iteritems():
    for revision in pagedetails["revisions"]:
        if revision["user"] == "TechBot":
            do.something()
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I can't access `revisions` from `pages`.
 `for revision in page["revisions"]: TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: my bad.  i did not notice that page would be the required key.  i have edited the answer for correctness